# Vue TypeScript Object prop type is not correct

Tags: typescript, vue.js

When using Object properties in Vue Single File Components in TypeScript (generated with Vue CLI 3), the type of the prop is not correct, as shown by the minimal example below.

The type of `this.product` is `(() => any) | ComputedOptions<any>`. Does anyone know of a solution to this?

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue, { PropType } from 'vue';

interface ProductInterface {
  units: number;
}

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'Product',
  props: {
    product: {
      type: Object as PropType<ProductInterface>,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    unitsString() {
      return `${this.product.units} Units`;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: This should work fine. Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put a type after the computed property like so?

```
unitsString() :string{
  return ... 
}
```

Typescript with Vue reacts weirdly with computed properties which are inferred.